# Add firestoreConnect to default export, react-redux-firebase

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

I am struggling to get the right syntax for an export.

I now have:

`export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Appbar)));`

Which is working like it should be. I now want to implement **firestoreConnect**. Something like this:

`firestoreConnect([{ collection: 'users'}])`

**Question: How do i combine these two together into 1 export**

I have seen several cases where you would use **compose** to combine those two lines.
I have not yet managed to do so...

Hope you guys can help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work like this:

```
const enhance = compose(
  withRouter,
  withStyles(styles),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  firestoreConnect([
    { collection: 'users' }
  ])
)

export default enhance(Appbar)
```